# Trigger an on screen keyboard on windows using react native

Tags: windows, react-native, keyboard

I am using a windows device with a touch screen, I would like for an input field that I have to open the on-screen windows keyboard, is there a way to do that in react native for windows?

Answer (score 0):

You can initiate focus on component mount. Give a ref to `TextInput` using `useRef()`.

```
const ref = useRef<TextInput|null>(null); // If you are using typescript

// If not then just 
// const ref = useRef();

React.useEffect(() => {
  ref.current?.focus();
}, []);

<TextInput ref={ref} {...otherProps} />;
```